# How can I create a parameterized bash alias?

Tags: bash

I would like to create a parameterized bash alias. I am not certain that is the correct way to describe it.

For example:

```
alias gps="gulp protractor --specs=test/browser/specs/<i-want-to-parameterize-this-bit>.js"
```

So that I can type:

```
gps foo/bar
```

...and the command resovles to:

```
alias gps="gulp protractor --specs=test/browser/specs/foo/bar.js"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell function:

```
gdiff() { 
   git diff --color=always "$@" | less -r
}
```

Another example:

```
foo() { /path/to/command "$@" ;}
foo arg1 arg2
```

You can create script, and pass arg.